# Change "Next File" and "Previous File" shortcut in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, keymapping

I'm having no luck changing the key bindings for switching files in Sublime. Does anybody know that the deal is here? All i'm trying to achieve is cmd+] and cmd+[ to show next and previous files. Then i can use tab and shift+tab for all my indenting.

```
[
   { "keys": ["super+]"], "command": "Next File" },
   { "keys": ["super+["], "command": "Previous File" }
]
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+]"], "command": "next_view" },
  { "keys": ["ctrl+["], "command": "prev_view" }
]
```

Of course this goes into the "Key Bindings - User" file.

Comment: perfect, thanks! How did you know it was 'view' and not 'file' by the way? I wasn't able to find a list of all the names of the commands.

Comment: You can open the default key bindings through `Preferences` -> `Key Binding - Default`. There I searched for `ctrl+pageup` which I know is the default key binding for "Next Page"

Comment: @alsweet As a general tip, you can also enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the console. This will display the command and arguments being run when a menu or keyboard action is run. Useful if you want to find what command is being run, without diving through keymap files.

Comment: thanks philipp, great tip, that will help a lot with editing my shortcuts. this switch from coda to sublime seems to be getting more and more worth it with every new feature i'm finding!

Comment: For OSX users this is achievable by default using `CMD` + `Shift` + `[` or `]` This applies to all tabbed apps.

Answer (score 16):

This is actually what you might have been really looking for.  I find it more useful to go back to the previous file I was working on, not moving left and right through the tabs. But you can have bindings to both behaviors.

```
// This is very useful, go back to the previously viewed file regardless of
// tab order
  { "keys": ["super+["], "command": "next_view_in_stack" },
  { "keys": ["super+]"], "command": "prev_view_in_stack" }
```

Comment: it seems like this only allows you to go back to the previous file *within* a group. It would be more useful to go back to any previous file, irrespective of whether it's in the same group.

Comment: Thanks, I think this should be the accepted answer! But for me it made more sense to reverse the command.